# Is there anyway to identify which email alias a sender used for me if it was listed as a BCC (Outlook)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, bcc

I'm using Outlook 2010 but my buddy, using Outlook 2003, doesn't seem to be able to see it either.

I know that if I open the email (external to viewing pane) and go to the [File] tab, then hit the [Properties] button, I can view the contents of the "Internet headers" but that doesn't have BCC information in it.

According to [section 3.6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.3) in RFC 2822 (internet standard for e-mail messages) there are three ways in which the "Bcc:" field should be implemented:

> 1. when a message containing a "Bcc:" field is prepared to be sent, the "Bcc:" line is removed even though all of the recipients (including those specified in the "Bcc:" field) are sent a copy of the message.
> 2. recipients specified in the "To:" and "Cc:" lines each are sent a copy of the message with the "Bcc:" line removed as above, but the recipients on the "Bcc:" line get a separate copy of the message containing a "Bcc:" line.  (When there are multiple recipient addresses in the "Bcc:" field, some implementations actually send a separate copy of the message to each recipient with a "Bcc:" containing only the address of that particular recipient.)
> 3. since a "Bcc:" field may contain no addresses, a "Bcc:" field can be sent without any addresses indicating to the recipients that blind copies were sent to someone.
>
> Which method to use with "Bcc:" fields is implementation dependent, but refer to the "Security Considerations" section of this document for a discussion of each.

If Outlook's implementation is based on the 1st way then I guess I'm SOL. Does anyone know if this the case?

Answer (score 1):

If you can view the raw message (view details and properties of the email) you should see a line like "Envelope-to: bccrecipient@example.com" with your BCC address.