# Finding BCC in Internet mail headers

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, spam-prevention, bcc

I am running Outlook 2010 connected to an Exchange 2003 server.  Often times, the spam that I received is sent to "undisclosed-recipients".  I'm guessing that's because my email address (or an email address for a group I am part of) is in the BCC field.

Is there a way to find out what BCC address was used to reach me?  I looked at the Internet Headers for the message, but am not seeing "Envelope-to", [described in a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/333590/is-there-anyway-to-identify-which-email-alias-a-sender-used-for-me-if-it-was-lis).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "BCC field"; BCC in email is performed by adding the recipient to the envelope but not the headers, which means that they are undetectable unless the email server is explicitly configured to reveal them somehow.

Comment: The Exchange admin was able to confirm the BCC address using the logs on the Exchange server itself.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4):

In the internet headers, you should see a line `Received by: xyz for <your email addr>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I do see my email address occasionally in other spam messages in a line similar to above.  Unfortunately, not in this particular email.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple test case I have created for the BCC field.

1. Create new email with BCC only.

   [image: Screen Shot]
2. Check the raw message at received end(Here I sent to Gmail). If you have a close look on the raw message in the screen shot with highlighted **for** then you can see the **BCC** which I have added while sending an email.

   [image: Screen Shot]

Comment: This only shows your own email address, that is, the email address shown in the headers is the email address from which you are checking you are mail. It does not show other BCC recipients. The example you show here is one in which you have sent and received a BCC email to the same email address.

Comment: @Meitar this thread is not about "other" BCC recipients. Looking at the message source worked in Thunderbird POP3, for mail from a spam sender, where the "recipient" was blank in the email header. My hosting provider has put my addressee email in the "for" locations as shown above. It is not my catchall address which is used to download POP3.